# How to make a post request to urlscanio using Go?

Tags: go

What I'm doing is trying to submit a URL to scan to urlscan.io. I can do a search but have issues with submissions, particularly correctly sending the right headers/encoded data.

from their site on how to submit a url:

curl -X POST "https://urlscan.io/api/v1/scan/" \
      -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
      -H "API-Key: $apikey" \
      -d "{\"url\": \"$url\", \"public\": \"on\"}"

This works to satisfy the Api key header requirement but

```
req.Header.Add("API-Key", authtoken)
```

This is my attempt that fails

```
data := make(url.Values)
data.Add("url", myurltoscan)
```

The URL property I have struggled with tremendously.

This is my error:
"message": "Missing URL properties",
  "description": "The URL supplied was not OK, please specify it including the protocol, host and path (e.g. http://example.com/bar)",
  "status": 400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url.Value` is a `map[string][]string` containing values used in query parameters or `POST` form. You would need it if you were trying to do something like:

```
curl -X GET https://urlscan.io/api/v1/scan?url=<urltoscan>
```

or

```
curl -X POST -F 'url=<urltoscan>' https://urlscan.io/api/v1/scan
```

See documentation https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values.

To send a regular POST request with JSON data, you can encode the JSON as bytes and send with `http.Post`:

```
var payload = []byte(`{"url":"<your-url>","public":"on"}`)
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, 
bytes.NewBuffer(payload))
req.Header.Set("API-Key", authtoken)
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

client := &http.Client{}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
        panic(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
```